# Expectation of quotient of linear combinations of independent standard normal random variables

Tags: random-variables, expectation

Let $a, b, c, d, e, f$ be complex numbers with nonnegative real parts and nonnegative imaginary parts, and let $X_{1}, X_{2}, X_{3}, X_{4}$ be independent standard normal random variables. How can I verify the following:

$$E\left[\frac{a X_{1} + b X_{2} + c X_{3} + d X_{4}}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right] = E \left[\frac{a X_{1} + b X_{2}}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right]?$$

Comment: Is this true?  The expectation on the left may be undefined.  I know if the numerator and denominator were independent then the ratio would be Cauchy, but I'm not sure what happens when they're correlated.

Comment: @dsaxton Very good concern, technically, we need to show the integrability first. But since he wrote expressions like that, I think the existence of expectation is pre-assumed.

Answer (score 0):

By linearity of expectation operator, we have:
\begin{equation}
E\left[\frac{a X_{1} + b X_{2} + c X_{3} + d X_{4}}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right] = E \left[\frac{a X_{1} + b X_{2}}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right] + E \left[\frac{c X_{3} + d X_{4}}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right] \quad (1)
\end{equation}
Note that the random variables $cX_3 + dX_4$ and $\frac{1}{eX_1 + fX_2}$ are independent, thus,
$$E \left[\frac{c X_{3} + d X_{4}}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right] = E \left[\frac{1}{e X_{1} + f X_{2}}\right] \times E(cX_3 + dX_4)$$
in which $E(cX_3 + dX_4) = cE(X_3) + dE(X_4) = 0$, by assumption. Hence the second term in $(1)$ vanishes and the desired result follows.

Comment: The condition may be relaxed to that only $X_3, X_4$ have zero means, and $(X_1, X_2)$ and $(X_3, X_4)$ are independent.

Comment: The problem with this argument is that E[1 / (eX_1 + fX_2)] doesn't exist, so we can't conclude that the latter expectation is zero (it's actually undefined).

Comment: I went through the same calculations as Zhanxiong, but I ran into the same problem that dsaxton pointed out. Hence, my post. To be more precise, I just updated the problem so that the constants $a, b, c, d$ are complex numbers with nonnegative real parts and nonnegative imaginary parts. That's it.

Comment: I am not sure if I can show $E(1/X)$ exists if $X$ is a standard normal variable mathematically right now. But the Monte Carlo study shows it is not diverge (nor converge).

Comment: $\text{E}(1 / X)$ does not exist.  In the second part you're taking the expectation of a Cauchy random variable, so we shouldn't be getting zero as the answer.